# Text and Image in RadRibbonBar Right Panel Start Menu Telerik

Tags: winforms, telerik

How can I insert only text and image in RadRibbonBar Right Panel Start Menu? Or How Can I make a custom form to be shown in RadRibbonBar Right Panel Start Menu?
It seems currently I can only insert separator, menu item, button and some other limited controls which are clickable and I can not insert simple label and image.

[image]

[image: Available items]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left side of the backstage you can add two types of items:
- buttons, which trigger some action, such as Save, Exit, Open
- tab item, which show a content area on the right side

In the example above, Save & Send is a tab item. On its right side, you can see a RadPageView control with couple pages/tabs (Send using email, Save to web, etc). And each of these tabs, show some content (controls) - Save using email, shows some buttons and labels.

So to answer your question, if you place a tab item on the left, on the right side you can place any controls you like - buttons, labels, grids, charts, anything.

Comment: Thank you man, I have edited my question and add another picture. I can not find TAB item!

Comment: TabItem you will find when the RibbonBar.ApplicationMenuStyle = Backstage. See here for more info: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/ribbonbar/backstage-view/working-with-backstage-view